# Play: How to deal with possible failures when deserializing an object form JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework, deserialization

Here below is a case class to be serialized/deserialized to/from JSON in a Play controller:

```
case class User(
  id: Option[BSONObjectID],
  email: String,
  password: Password
)

object User {
  ...
  implicit val userReads: Reads[User] = (
    (__ \ '_id).readNullable[BSONObjectID] ~
    (__ \ 'email).read[String](email) ~
    (__ \ 'password).read(
      (
        (__ \ 'hashtext).read[String] ~
        (__ \ 'salt).readNullable[String]
    )(Password.apply(_: String, _: Option[String]).get))
  )(User.apply _)
}
```

The code above compiles and works fine... but I'm wondering how to deal with possible failures when *applying* the password. If you look at [Password.scala](https://github.com/gokillo/brix/blob/master/brix-corelib/src/main/scala/brix/security/Password.scala) you'll see I made the constructor private and created an `apply` method in the companion object that returns a `Try`... but of course I cannot assume it always returns `Success` and just invoke `get`. Having said that, should I invoke `getOrElse` and throw an exception?

```
object User {
  ...
  implicit val userReads: Reads[User] = (
    ...
    (__ \ 'password).read(
      (
        (__ \ 'hashtext).read[String] ~
        (__ \ 'salt).readNullable[String]
    )(Password.apply(_: String, _: Option[String]).getOrElse{throw new Exception}))
  )(User.apply _)
}
```

Or is there a better option to deal with failures when deserializing an object from JSON?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `JsResult`, which is a lot like `Try`.  It has two subtypes: `JsSuccess` and `JsError`.

```
val json = Json.parse("...")

json.validate[User] match {
  case JsSuccess(user, _) => println("Got a user: " + user)
  case JsError(errors)    => println("Errors! " + errors.mkString)
}
```

You can use `filter` in a `Reads` in order to check conditions: [reference](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads)

An example is [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) under "Manipulating a JsResult[A]"

Comment: OK that's fine... but how do I forward the exception contained in the Try returned by Password.apply?